# Is it possible to use ESP32, BLE4 or BT 2 and WiFi same time?

Tags: bluetooth, esp8266, wifi, bluetooth-low-energy

I am planning to use ESP32 module to transfer data using wifi (ESP32 web server AP)to remote PC and also the same time I need BLE to communicate with a mobile app and get some data to eps32.

so I will be needing to use both wifi connection and ble same time
is it possible to use or establish wifi and ble same time (in the loop WIFI data transmission 1st and then BLE date receive)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one antenna/radio unit but it is possible to use the special option "Software controls WiFi/Bluetooth coexistence" to allow both protocols to be used within the same system. You can quickly run into issues if you are trying to have a high throughput or low latency but from the espressif FAQ:

> "At the moment, ESP32 can simultaneously function as a Wi-Fi module
>   and as a Bluetooth speaker, playing music smoothly"

For more details see section 5.3 on Coexistince from the Espressif FAQ:
https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/ESP32_FAQs__EN.pdf

If you expect to have fairly high throughput and require low latency for near real-time data you may want to explore using an external bluetooth module like the HC-05 (master+slave) or HC-06 (slave only) for bluetooth communications and enable only wifi on your base ESP32 device.

Comment: wifi will have higher data rate around 20Mbps, but BLE will be less than 1Mbps. will it be a issue?

Comment: i am not using BT 2 and BLE same time.. i need ble and wifi same time